# Xamarin Android: recyclerview deselect all when press the back button on contextual action mode don t work

Tags: xamarin.android

Hello Everyone my name is Taniguchi.

I've created a recyclerview and inserted a contextual action mode.

when i select a item on my recyclerview the contextual action mode appears and there is no items selected the contextual action mode finishes.

But if a click on the back button on the contextual action mode the items stays selected.

My mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    public static CheckBox checkbox1;
    public static BottomNavigationView bottomnavigationview1;
    public static FloatingActionButton floatinactionbutton1;
    public int position;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    private ActionMode mode;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViwer);
        bottomnavigationview1 = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>
          (Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);


        floatinactionbutton1 = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>
          (Resource.Id.fab);
        bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        mRecyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.Context, DividerItemDecoration.Vertical));
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        SetupList();


        //Create our layout Manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);



    }

    private void SetupList()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            mEmails = new List<Email>();
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });


        }
    }
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    private View view;
    private Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Boolean IsSelected()
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
    {
        isSelected = selected;
    }


    public static bool unselect = false;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private MyActionMode mActionMode;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    private Context context;
    private View v;
    private ActionMode mode;
    public static bool count = false;
    public static int CountAuxiliar = 0;
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public  RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }
    public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mName { get; set; }
        public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
        public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

        public MyView(View view) : base(view)
        {
            mMainView = view;
        }

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mEmails.Count; }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
        return vh;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
        myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
        myHolder.cbx.Checked = mEmails[position].IsSelected();
        if(MyActionMode.ismenuactivated == false){
            myHolder.cbx.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
        myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
        myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;


        myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
        myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
        myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
        myHolder.ItemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (CountAuxiliar > 0 && mode != null)
        {
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
            {
                CountAuxiliar++;
            }
            else
            {
                CountAuxiliar--;
            }
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + CountAuxiliar + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        if (CountAuxiliar < 1 && count == true)
        {
          count = false;
          mode.Finish();
          MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
          MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
    public bool OnLongClick(View v)
    {

        if (CountAuxiliar < 1)
        {
            CountAuxiliar = 1;
            count = true;
            int position = (int)v.Tag;
            mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
            v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent); MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            MainActivity.floatinactionbutton1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity, this, position);
            mode = mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
            mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionado";
            count = true;

            Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position].IsSelected() + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Contextual Action Mode Class:

```
public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RecyclerViewHolder holder;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private int currentPosition;
    private Button button;
    public View v;
    public static bool ismenuactivated = true;
    private IMenu menu;
    private View menuItemView;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    public CheckBox cbx;
    public View itemView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public MyActionMode(Context context) : this(context, null, 0)
    {

    }


    public MyActionMode(Context context, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int position)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        currentPosition = position;
    }

    public MyActionMode(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                // do Update
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
        //------------------------------------------

        button = (Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemTwoId).ActionView;
        button.Background = null;
        var draw = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mContext, Resource.Drawable.three_dots);
        button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
        button.Click += delegate {
            PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(mContext, button);
            menu1.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
            menu1.Show();
        };

        return true;
    }


    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        mEmails[currentPosition].setSelected(false);
        mView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        mView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        mAdapter.NotifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
        mode.Dispose();
    }
```

The errors is occurring on the OnDestroyActionMode class:
In the lines:

```
mEmails[currentPosition].setSelected(false);
        mView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        mView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        mAdapter.NotifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
```

The error message says:
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we press the back button in context action mode, we should deselect all the options, right?Then we can achieve like this:

In `MyActionMode`,modify the function `OnDestroyActionMode` as follows:

```
public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        mAdapter.removeSelection();//removeSelection is a function of RecyclerAdapter  
        mode.Dispose();
    }
```

And add function `removeSelection` in the RecyclerAdapter

```
 public void removeSelection()
    {
        //assign all the value of `IsSelected` to false of mEmails list

         if (mEmails!=null ) {
           foreach (Email email in mEmails) {
              email.setSelected(false);
           }
        }

        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Meanwhile, if we want to deselect some special position Item, we can add the following method in `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
public void removeSpecialSelection(int position) {
        mEmails[position].setSelected(false);

        // other logic code

        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And call above method in method `OnDestroyActionMode`

```
public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
       // mAdapter.removeSelection();

        mAdapter.removeSpecialSelection(currentPosition);
        mode.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I just  want to add :

Comment: on destroyaction mode before call the method removeselection()

Comment: add:                      RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails,this);